# Recoverable and Cascadeless schedules

Tags: sql, database, database-design, transactions

I was given the following schedule, and couldn't tell why it is cascadeless, hence recoverable too.

I understand that there has to be a transaction T2, that reads data written by T1, only after T1 commits, for the schedule to be cascadeless. But the below schedule does not have the following format. Can someone please explain to me what is happening here.

Link to the schedule below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEG3u.png